# laravel old para selectores cargados dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, xmlhttprequest

Bien, el problema es el siguiente.
Tengo 3 selectores, llamemoslo A, B y C.

B y C se cargan de forma dinamica con peticiones XMLHTTPRequest... B depende de lo que elija en A y C depende de lo que se elija en B.

Ahora, como el formulario obviamente tiene muchos mas campos, estos los valido en controlador con la funcion **validate de Laravel** y es ahi donde radica mi problema.

Laravel ofrece la variable **old()** para que en caso de que no se cumplan las validaciones, se devuelve a la vista del formulario y la variable **old()** hace que se mantengan escritos los campos que ya habiamos enviado.

Pero en mi formulario, no se como mostrar los valores **old** para mis selectores, ya que tecnicamente, no existen.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="Departamento">Localidad:</label>
    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" value="{{old('departamento')}}" id="departamento" name="departamento">
        <option value="">Seleccione un Departamento</option>
        @foreach ($departamentos as $departamento)
            <option value="{{$departamento->id}}" {{ old('departamento') == $departamento->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{$departamento->nombre}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    @error('departamento')
        <small class="text-danger">
            {{ $message }}
        </small>
    @enderror
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="provincia" name="provincia">
        <option value="">Seleccione una provincia</option>

    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <select class="form-control form-control-sm var-precio"  id="municipio" name="municipio">
        <option value=''>Seleccione un municipio</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Como ven, el primero si tiene varios options, pero los otros dos aun no, porque se van cargando con HTTPRequest

Alguna idea?